# MapReduce operation recursively

Tags: recursion, mapreduce, hbase

I have a hbase basetable A on which I call Mapper and Reducer class from my code. The result that I obtain, table A-first, I have to call same Mapper and Reducer on it again. Is it possible to do it at all? I have to do the recursion 3 times, as the table A is extremely large and my MapReduce works to aggregate the table 3 ways on time stamps.

And is it possible to do it without creating table A-first first i.e. send the data obtained from Reducer back to Mapper (table is created but MapReduce is performed on data after reducer rather than accessing table A-first)?

Comment: Have you considered using Spark?

Comment: i am trying to do it through Java program!

Comment: Spark has java api as well...